# Populating a dynamic array with cellvalues from one column VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following problem: I imported a .csv file with my data into a separate worksheet called "Import".

In this QueryTable, I have the second column called "KW", which indicates the weeknumber for every row.

Now I wanted to populate an array with the cell values from the second column.

I need to make it dynamic, because the length of the array changes with each import.

So far I made the code below:

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable()


Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim TempArray() As Variant
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim x As Long

Sheets("Import").Activate

Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("database_all")

TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)

myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(x)
  Next x

End Sub
```

I get the "runtime error 13": types not compatible

I get the error, but I don't know what exactly I need to change. Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: Try `TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).Value`.

Comment: ...or remove the parentheses in the description of this variable - just `Dim TempArray As Variant`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `Dim` and use `Set`:

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable()
    
    
    Dim myArray() As Variant '*** will be a 1D VBA array
    Dim TempArray As Range   '*** typical 2D range variable as part of a column
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    
    Sheets("Import").Activate
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("database_all")
    Set TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)
    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
    
    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an arraylist instead as it provides more flexibility. For example you can do something like this:

Sub test()

```
Dim arr As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
j = 2

'Filling arrayLists
For i = 2 To lastRow
    arr.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
Next i

'Read from arrayLists
For i = 0 To arr.Count - 1
        Cells(j, 3) = arr(i)
        j = j + 1
Next i
```

End Sub

Customize the code as required. It should resolve your issue.